# Pentaho Report Designer MongoDB grouping by epoch timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb, pentaho-report-designer

My first StackOverflow post!

I have a MongoDB collection called user_sessions - a single document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e352bbed3e4af00d8b459a"),
    "active_date" : 1407406779727,
    "auth_token" : "WObDF9KO6n1V34lgjlFIoXoiEmOH9CM8",
    "device_token" : "3474ac2d5aa9c7dc933bd4548c2dd6ea3d8a9592dad1c1a807c06ac2c8459205",
    "device_type" : "1",
    "end_time" : "",
    "sessionid" : "",
    "start_time" : 1407406779727,
    "userid" : "53e352bbed3e4af00d8b4599"
}
```

I'm trying to create a report using Pentaho's Report Designer (5.1). 
I have managed to output the total number of user sessions with this query:

```
[
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]
```

which is great.

However, I'd like to also show the number of sessions by date.

When I run this PHP script against that collection (using the PHP Mongo driver):

```
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
$c_us = $db->user_session;
$cursor = $c_us->find();
foreach ( $cursor as $document ) {
    echo "<br/>UserID: " . $document['userid'] . ", StartTime: ";
    $epoch = $document['start_time'];
    echo date('Y-m-d',$epoch/1000); 
}
```

I get this output:

```
UserID: 53dfa1a7ed3e4aef0d8b456b, StartTime: 2014-08-05
UserID: 53e075deed3e4af00d8b4570, StartTime: 2014-08-05
UserID: 53e079c9ed3e4af00d8b4573, StartTime: 2014-08-05
UserID: 53e07f8ded3e4aef0d8b4580, StartTime: 2014-08-05
UserID: 53e081f9ed3e4aef0d8b4583, StartTime: 2014-08-05
UserID: 53e352bbed3e4af00d8b4599, StartTime: 2014-08-07
UserID: 53e9fb9eed3e4af00d8b45a3, StartTime: 2014-08-12
UserID: 53f215f6ed3e4aef0d8b45a3, StartTime: 2014-08-19
UserID: 53f3eeb7ed3e4aef0d8b45a7, StartTime: 2014-08-20
UserID: 54083e94ed3e4af00d8b45b0, StartTime: 2014-09-04
UserID: 5412cd29ed3e4aef0d8b45bc, StartTime: 2014-09-12
UserID: 54175625ed3e4aef0d8b45c0, StartTime: 2014-09-16
UserID: 54351b7ced3e4af00d8b45ff, StartTime: 2014-10-08
UserID: 5444f1dced3e4a56718b45bb, StartTime: 2014-10-20
UserID: 54475d48ed3e4af00d8b4628, StartTime: 2014-10-22
UserID: 5449cc77ed3e4a79638b4592, StartTime: 2014-10-24
UserID: 53e3c875ed3e4af00d8b459d, StartTime: 2014-10-24
UserID: 544f6bb7ed3e4af00d8b464a, StartTime: 2014-10-28
UserID: 544de95aed3e4a56718b45f2, StartTime: 2014-10-31
UserID: 545b125c4a4ddd30048b4567, StartTime: 2014-11-06
```

Fantastic!

But how can I do a count of sessions by date (and month/date)?

So for the above, I need reports like this:

```
2014-08-05    5
2014-08-07    1
.
.
.
2014-10-24    2
```

etc

and

```
Month/Year     Count
Aug 2014       9
Sep 2014       3
Oct 2014       7
Nov 2014       1
```

Given the user_session schema, how can I convert the epoch time in start_time to Month/Year and count?

My keyword research hasn't given my anything I can try either.

I'm at a loss. What should I be entering as my search term?
Can someone give me some pointers?

I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Brad

Comment: Sorry I'm not super familiar with pentaho or PHP but MongoDB has some excellent date aggregators you can use, they're outlined here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators

Comment: @ranman ! Thanks! I followed the $month link and ended up here [link]http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month[/link] and I changed their example but get this error:

`
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):15

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type NumberDouble to Date",
 "code" : 16006,
 "ok" : 0
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, there are the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) you can use to dissect things like [**`$year`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) and [**`$month`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) and [**`$dayOfMonth`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) into grouping keys for the aggregation framework as follows:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "year": { "$year": "$start_time" },
           "month": { "$month": "$start_time" },
           "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$start_time" }
       },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }}
])
```

But if you are comfortable with "epoch timestamp" values then you can always use this basic match trick with "date" objects and "date math" in general, to produce an epoch timestamp rounded to your required value:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$start_time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { "$mod": [
                     { "$subtract": [ "$start_time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                     1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
)
```

With the basic trick there being that when you "subtract" or do other similar math from one "date" object to another then the result is the "difference in milliseconds" from the objects as an integer. In the example given `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` this is equal to **one day** in time, and by the modulo the value is rounded to the current day.

This gives an alternate approach to the date aggregation operators, where it might be desired to actually receive the "timestamp" value.

Since all input to the aggregation pipeline will be "serialized" on submission, then all valid "dat objects" in any given language that are supported by the driver will end up as a correct input value. We are just using the "epoch" date here to "convert" the date object value present in the collection to an integer.

It depends on what you prefer as output. Some people prefer the "integer" form as an easy cast to a new "date" object. Some are happy with the individual field parts to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Neil - I tried your first code (replacing your "collection" with my "user_session") and got this error:

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type NumberDouble to Date",
 "code" : 16006,
 "ok" : 0
}

and your 2nd example:

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: cant $subtract aDate from a NumberDouble",
 "code" : 16556,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @bradzo Which means you are not actually storing "date" types but just timestamp numeric values. Use the **second** method, without the subtractions from date objects since the values should already be "epoch" timestamp values. And possibly not in milliseconds, so look at your data and optionally drop the `1000` multiplier.

Comment: #Neil thank you - when I drop the #subtract stuff, I get the same as I outlined in my original post - just a count of entries ie: 20. I just don't know how to convert that epoch timestamp (which needs to be / 1000 in the PHP script to give me the correct date) into a date object. I've read that its not possible. Perhaps I should use a Groovy script (remember, ultimate query will be executed by Pentaho report server) - THanks for your help.

Comment: @bradzo As I said. Your data is not a "date" type. So if it is not a date and not an integer or double then it is a string. Do you see the problem here? You need to fix your data.

Comment: yes, getting in touch with developers now - will let you know how I go, but thank you lots. I really appreciate your help.